# ffmpeg decode, get avFrame(yuv420p), yuv to rgb by shader, but it is so green

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

[image: shader is in the image]

I use ffmpeg to decode `xxx.mp4` and get YUV420p `AVFrame`. Then I render the yuv data by shader, but it is so green!

```
uTextureYLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, uTextureY);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, yTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, avFrame->width, avFrame->height, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, avFrame->data[0]);
glUniform1i(uTextureYLocation, 0);

uTextureULocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, uTextureU);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, uTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, avFrame->width / 2, avFrame->height / 2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             avFrame->data[1]);
glUniform1i(uTextureULocation, 1);

uTextureVLocation = glGetUniformLocation(program, uTextureV);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, vTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, avFrame->width / 2, avFrame->height / 2, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             avFrame->data[2]);
glUniform1i(uTextureVLocation, 2);
```

Comment: I don't know if it helps or you already know, that all zero'ed YUV buffers ends up green picture.

Comment: if i only use Y, video is black and white. But use U and V, video looks so green

Comment: That is because, as you might know Y plane is grayscale part of the picture. For some reason, your YUV frame filled with zeros (0x00). Something wrong with your conversion scheme. Can you check whether the YUV frame is OK before conversion ?